# Why does a:hover get overriden in CSS?

Tags: css, hyperlink, overriding, hover

If I have this CSS:

```
a:link { color: blue; }
a:hover { color: red; }
#someID a:link { color: black; }
```

Links under the ID always appears in black on hover. I'm aware that using an ID gives a higher priority, however, I'm not overriding the `:hover` selector, only the `:link` selector, so shouldn't the hover display in red?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `:link` pseudo class applies to the link even when you are hovering over it. As the style with the id is more specific it overrides the others.

The only reason that the `:hover` style overrides the `:link` style at all is that it comes later in the style sheet. If you place them in this order:

```
a:hover { color: red; }
a:link { color: blue; }
```

the `:link` style is later in the style sheet and overrides the `:hover` style. The link stays blue when you hover over it.

To make the `:hover` style work for the black link you have to make it at least as specific as the `:link` style, and place it after it in the style sheet:

```
a:link { color: blue; }
a:hover { color: red; }
#someID a:link { color: black; }
#someID a:hover { color: red; }
```

Comment: Thanks for info. I've actually decided to use an !important rule on the original hover to override later rules. This saves me having to add #someID a:hover { color: red; } every time a link gets overriden.

Answer (score -2):

There's an order issue, as explained in W3Schools:

> Note: a:hover MUST come after a:link
>   and a:visited in the CSS definition in
>   order to be effective!!
>
> Note: a:active MUST come after a:hover
>   in the CSS definition in order to be
>   effective!!

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Reordering the styles is not enough to make the :hover work for the black link.

Comment: Maybe incomplete (also has to have the same priority in CSS), but not wrong at all. This behaviour is described in W3C standards.